# Does constructing a Uint8Array from a plain array even make sense here?

Tags: javascript

I would like to use the following library in IE9, but the latter doesn't support Uint8Array or generally typed arrays.

A Uint8Array wrapper is used exactly once in the code, to me it actually seems redundant though. Can you confirm?

Line 71: http://www.perry.cz/files/ExifRestorer.js (just a very small lib to extract Exif information from a JPEG)

The insertExif function returns a plain array, which exifManipulation then puts into a Uint8Array prior to base64 encoding:

```
var image = this.exifManipulation(resizedFileBase64 /*plain string*/, segments /*plain array of plain arrays*/);
this.encode64(image);

...

ExifRestorer.exifManipulation = function(resizedFileBase64, segments)
{
        var exifArray = this.getExifArray(segments), /*plain array*/
            newImageArray = this.insertExif(resizedFileBase64, exifArray), /*plain array*/
            aBuffer = new Uint8Array(newImageArray);

        return aBuffer;
};

ExifRestorer.encode64 = function(input)
{
    var output = "",
        chr1, chr2, chr3 = "",
        enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4 = "",
        i = 0;

    do {
        chr1 = input[i++];
        chr2 = input[i++];
        chr3 = input[i++];

        enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
        enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
        enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
        enc4 = chr3 & 63;

        if (isNaN(chr2)) {
           enc3 = enc4 = 64;
        } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
           enc4 = 64;
        }

        output = output +
           this.KEY_STR.charAt(enc1) +
           this.KEY_STR.charAt(enc2) +
           this.KEY_STR.charAt(enc3) +
           this.KEY_STR.charAt(enc4);
        chr1 = chr2 = chr3 = "";
        enc1 = enc2 = enc3 = enc4 = "";
    } while (i < input.length);

    return output;
};
```

As I understand the code, it works internally with plain arrays anyway. It doesn't use the Uint8Array as a view on an ArrayBuffer as originally intended by the typed array specification, it simply passes the plain array into the constructor.

I fail to see the point of putting it into the Uint8Array here, instead of directly returning the underlying numeric array (each element in the [0, 255] range for single bytes). And indeed the code does work without the Uint8Array wrapper in my tests with IE9 on Windows 7.

Is there anything I'm missing or are there possible scenarios or environments where accessing individual elements from the underlying numeric array directly rather than through the Uint8Array view would return faulty or unreliable results in the encode64 function? I can't quite imagine any.

There is no official support for the library, hence my question here. Thanks everybody for looking into it.

Comment: Can you post the relevant lines of code in the question itself, please?

Comment: Anybody? :( If the question isn't clear please let me know.